# StyleCop.Analyzers: Disable SA1633 & SA1652

Tags: stylecop

I have already consulted the [configuration documentation](https://github.com/DotNetAnalyzers/StyleCopAnalyzers/blob/master/documentation/Configuration.md), but couldn't find anything.

I want to disable both of the following rules:

```
SA1633: The file header is missing or not located at the top of the file.
SA1652: Enable XML documentation output.
```

My `stylecop.json` looks like this:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DotNetAnalyzers/StyleCopAnalyzers/master/StyleCop.Analyzers/StyleCop.Analyzers/Settings/stylecop.schema.json",
  "settings": {
    "orderingRules": {
      "usingDirectivesPlacement": "outsideNamespace"
    }
  }
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Enabling and disabling rules is done via a ruleset file, not the configuration `.json` file.  For details regarding use of ruleset files, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264996.aspx.

Comment: Oh no. I just read "Settings.StyleCop is not supported, but a stylecop.json file may be used to customize the behavior of certain rules." and went into the details of the stylecop.json... Thank you for pointing that out! https://github.com/DotNetAnalyzers/StyleCopAnalyzers/blob/master/StyleCop.Analyzers/StyleCop.Analyzers.ruleset got me started for the rule sets btw.

Answer (score 4):

Alternative way is to specify suppression attributes in GlobalSuppressions.cs, like this:

```
[assembly: System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("StyleCop.CSharp.DocumentationRules", "SA1633:File must have header", Justification = "<Pending>")]
[assembly: System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("StyleCop.CSharp.DocumentationRules", "SA1652:Enable XML documentation output", Justification = "<Pending>")]
```

Comment: Can GlobalSuppressions.cs be use for solution?

Comment: @mardok Yes, you can create a single file as a solution item and add it as a linked item in each project. It's also quite common to do with project info shared across the solution.